# call function declare in one js file from another js file in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
function getVehcile(){
 var vehcile = new array();

}
```

getvehiclefunction is present in Common.js file

I want to call this function from another another js file

How can i do this ??

Comment: So long as `common.js` is included in the page before `getvehiclefunction()` is called, there should be no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to ensure your `getvehiclefunction` is included first. It should be enough just to make sure your `Common.js` file is included before your other JavaScript:

```js
<script src="path/to/Common.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/another.js"></script>
```